# How to discover enode addresses on local network (in private test network)

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, peers, bootnodes, lighthouse

how i can broadcast a enode address to another physical machine on the same network, in geth

take for example, this as my enode address:

`"enode://d542cd9b172b59612d67b02ea2ac3f1f4a4e6e4b8e2760a35ba4806151a7@127.0.0.1:31303?discport=0"`

as you can see, it is tied to localhost and port 31303

how then, can this enode be discovered by geth running on another machine ( albeit on the same Local network )

P.S : for context, this is a local network - with separate Linux Server machines that we're trying to connect to each other. We're running a PoS private testnet based on geth + lighthouse

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bootnode` tool (comes with `geth`) to generate the enode address for any particular node on your network. Then you can specify the list of such nodes as, the `trusted nodes` or `static nodes` in the `toml` config in the `[Node.P2P]` section:

```
# generate the private key and store it in enode.key
bootnode --genkey enode.key;
# generates the public key of the node and displays it
bootnode --nodekey=enode.key --writeaddress
# for example: 01234567....abcdef
```

You can generate the config toml file for your geth command with

```bash
geth <your args> dumpconfig > config.toml
```

Then edit the file by adding the enode address into the `StaticNodes` list :

```bash
StaticNodes = ["enode://01234567...abcdef@<ip-address>:30303"]
```

Finally, start your node with

```bash
geth --config config.toml --nodekey enode.key
```